# Set the content of Bootstrap tooltip via Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

I have included tooltips in my table's cells. Here is how I did it:

```
<td data-container="body" data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true" data-original-title="10.5">10.5</td>

<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".table td").tooltip();   
      });
</script>
```

Until here, I don't have a problem. Now, I want to change the way it works. I have two dictionaries from numeric to text translations.

```
dic1 = {'0':'zero','1':'one','2':'two','3':'three'....}
dic2 = {'0.25':'a quarter','0.5':'half',....}
```

Numbers in the table are standards, so there isn't something that I don't have in dictionaries.
I want to change the title of the tooltips to this: `one half (1.5)` instead of `1.5`. Splitting the number and take the text from one dictionary and the text from the other and then combine them.

Adding just the tooltip was easy, but now I think that I am stacked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested it, but something like this should work.

```
$('.table td').each(function () {
    var title = $(this).attr('data-original-title').split('.');
    $(this).attr('data-original-title', dic1[title[0]] + ' ' +
        dic2['0.' + title[1]] + ' (' + title[0] + '.' + title[1] + ')');
});
```

Comment: Please, edit your answer with the following. 1) You miss one parenthesis before the last ';'. The one that close the `attr`. 2) change the `title` with `data-original-title`. And it works. Please change it so I can choose your answer as the right one. Thank you a lot!

Comment: I'm not sure why it needs to be `data-original-title`, but I have corrected it. Glad it helped, next time I will test things. :)